# recursive anagram in java

Tags: java, list, recursion, arraylist

I am having trouble implementing the algorithm to find the anagrams in a given string. The method below doesn't return the correct output. For example, given the word "abc" it returns [abc, bc, c, bc, bc, c]. When it should really just be [abc, bac, bca, acb, cab, acb]

```
private List<String> anagramizeRecursive(String word) {
    if(word.length() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length()-1; i++) {
            unfiltered.add(word.substring(i));
            anagramizeRecursive(word.substring(i+1));
            unfiltered.add(word.substring(i+1));
        }
    }
    return unfiltered;
}
```

Comment: Where is `unfiltered` list been instantiated ?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @JorgeCampos its a class variable it's an arraylist of strings

Comment: @Masud it's missing the anagrams with a in the front, I'm assuming since bc and c are repeated

Comment: Are you sure you're attempting to find anagrams? If so, you'll probably need to pass some lists along the recursion frames.

Answer (score 0):

For each character in the original string, you want to move that character to the front and then add it to all the anagrams made from the rest of the strings.

```
List<String> anagramRecursive(String word)
  result = empty list
  if word.isEmpty() result.add("")
  else 
    for each character c in word
      for each item in anagramRecursive(word-c)
        result.add(c + item)
  return result
```

There are many other ways of structuring the recursion, but that is most like what you have already.

Comment: to do this, would I have to convert word to an array of characters and loop through each character?

Answer (score 0):

From https://www.techiedelight.com/generate-permutations-string-java-recursive-iterative/

```
private static void permutations(String candidate, String remaining)
        {
            if (remaining.length() == 0) {
                System.out.println(candidate);
            }
    
        for (int i = 0; i < remaining.length(); i++)
        {
            String newCandidate = candidate + remaining.charAt(i);

            String newRemaining = remaining.substring(0,i) + remaining.substring(i + 1);

            permutations(newCandidate, newRemaining);
        }
    }

public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s = "ABC";
        permutations("", s);
    }
```